# How to get min value as sql query with a single row and multiple column value

Tags: mysql, min

I want to get minimum value from sql data.

I have ten columns in sql database:

```
Id   User   S1   S2   S3   S4   S5   S6   S7   S8   S8  S9   S10
1    Tom    12   13   65   34   7    32   45   6    18  10   12
```

My Question is how will I get **Minimum value and Total Value** as SQL query.

Second question:

If few values become same then any min value of any Column will output. how?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please display your code. You have to display some efforts.

Comment: Please format your code and also include table definition with a query which you tried to solve your issue

Comment: This kind of problem is symptomatic of poor design

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wanted to retrieve the **Minimum Value** and **Total of all Values** for each row, you could use the following SQL:

```
SELECT *, 
LEAST(S1,S2,S3,S4,S5,S6,S7,S8,S9,S10) as 'Minimum Value',
SUM(S1+S2+S3+S4+S5+S6+S7+S8+S9+S10) as 'Total Value'
From MyTable
```

(Note:  You could remove/alter the asterisk if you didn't want to view the other fields, but this works best for demonstration)

Based on the example row you provided, this query returns:

```
| Id | User | S1 | S2 | S3 | S4 | S5 | S6 | S7 | S8 | S9 | S10 | Minimum Value | Total Value |
+----+------+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----------------+-------------+
|  1 | Tom  | 12 | 13 | 65 | 34 |  7 | 32 | 45 |  6 | 18 |  10 |       6       |     242     |
```

Comment: Thanks friend. Your solution saved my time.

Answer (score 0):

Try this for min column and for total try simple +

```
SELECT LEAST(
    S1,
    S2,
    ....
)
FROM yourtable
```